# Jmeter loadtesting with nginx

Tags: nginx, jmeter

I have done jmeter load testing and it was working fine.
Now i am doing jmeter load testing with ngnix by configuring two server details .

I am testing my application by giving the 1000 concurrent users with nginx url.

Sometimes it was working and sometimes not.
Why it is behaving like that??

Comment: What do you mean "Sometimes it was working and sometimes not"
What kind of errors, what statuses, what responces?

Comment: Given that it works sometimes and the correct nginx url is used, the behaviour you experience should be because of a configuration issue in the nginx side. The load balancer might not be routing the messages to the servers properly. Check the nginx.conf file in the nginx server for the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs — nginx logs, your app and server logs and JMeter logs. Probably you can find answer there:
Check `nginx.conf` and find `error_log` settings to get current nginx error log location.

What do you mean "sometimes not"? What kind of errors, statuses and responces do you get?
You may post in here.